# Handsontable - get data via ajax and set autocomplete on one column

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, handsontable

I'm trying to pull data via ajax (this works) into the handsontable spreadsheet plugin. I have an array that i want to do autocomplete on one column. My output is a blank spreadsheet. If I comment out completely the "columns" portion it works perfectly - without the autocomplete. Please help me figure this out. This is my code:

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<script src="./lib/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="./dist/jquery.handsontable.full.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="./dist/jquery.handsontable.full.css">
<script src="./lib/jquery-ui/js/jquery-ui.custom.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="./lib/jquery-ui/css/ui-bootstrap/jquery-ui.custom.css">
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    first = true;
    $("#controllers").handsontable
    ({
        autoWrapRow: true,
        columns:[{},{},{
            //type: 'autocomplete',
            //source: ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"],
            //strict: true,
            //allowInvalid: false //true is default
        }]
    });
    var controllers = new Array();
    $.ajax
    ({
        url:"./get_controllers.php",
        type:"POST",
        dataType:"json",
        success:function(msg)
        {
            controllers = msg;
            $("#controllers").handsontable("loadData", controllers);
        }
    });
});
</script>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
        <div id="controllers" class="dataTable"></div>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, if you overwrite the columns property, then you need to set all the values yourself (for example, see this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uo273yez/)

To answer your more specific question about the autocomplete, you need to define the source of the autocomplete to be a function similar to this one: (also see [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3gvwr3d9/))

```
function (query, process){
    var msg = getJson(); //this is to simulate an Ajax Call
    process(msg.Colors);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to specify data property. Here is my code for object source (for array source http://handsontable.com/demo/datasources.html):

**1) Load data:**

```
$parent.find('button[name=load]').click(function () {
$.ajax({
    url: "/userajax/getmechanic/?id="+pid,
    type: 'GET',
    context: document.body
}).done(function(resp) {

        jsonObj = JSON.parse(resp);
        //load data to source
        objectData = jsonObj.data;
        $container.handsontable('render');
    });});
```

**2) Set :**

```
function setTable($container){
$container.handsontable({
    data: objectData,
    startRows: 5,

    columns: [
        {data: "id", readOnly: true},
        {   data:"user",
            type: 'autocomplete',
            source: users,
            strict: false
        }],
       ...
```